# Show that $f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x+y}$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $\mathbb R$ with euclidean topology, $\mathbb R^2$ with product topology and $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(a,-a)|a \in \mathbb R\}$ with subspace topology. How do I show that $$f:\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(a,-a)|a \in \mathbb R\}\to\mathbb R \quad \text{such that}\,f(x,y)=\frac{x}{x+y}$$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A := \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (a,-a) \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \}$. I hope you believe me when I say that $g,h : A \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $g(x,y) := x$ and $h(x,y) := x+y$, are continuous. Then their quotient $g/h$ is continuous if $g(x,y) \neq 0$ for all $(x,y)\in A$. This is indeed the case, since $g(x,y)=0$ implies $y=-x$, but points of the form $(x,-x)$ are not contained in $A$. So $g(x,y)/h(x,y) = x/(x+y)$ is continuous. Hope this helps!